# How to convert Chronicles Instant to datetime in excel?

Tags: excel, datetime, excel-formula

I've got an instant numeric value: **5466835506**
It's supposed to be this value: **3/27/2014  13:25**

I don't know how to convert this in excel. Can anyone help? Here are a few more examples of numbers I don't know:

5330070552

5357964810

5567063757

Comment: @ScottCraner Yes it does work! Why does the '-21548' part work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is the number of seconds since `1/1/1840`.  Since Excel only sees dates after 1900 we need to subtract `21548` days to make it work:

```
=(A1/(24*60*60))-21548
```

Make sure to format the date/time accordingly.

[image]